# Python tkinter filedialog asopenfilename

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a class and within that class I am having a window that will hold certain widgets (labels, buttons and entry-boxes) when i am using the filedialog.askopenfilename the original window gets closed and does not come back. Is there something I can do?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import filedialog    

class Editor():

    def __init__(self, master):

        # Variablen definieren
        self.fname = StringVar()    
        # Variable belegen
        self.master = master

        # Screen auf Seitengröße anpassen
        b = 700
        h = 500
        ao = int((self.master.winfo_screenheight() - h) / 2)
        al = int((self.master.winfo_screenwidth() - b) / 2)
        self.master.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(b, h, al, ao))

        # Fenster Name festlegen
        self.master.title('Editor')

        # Farbe des Hintergrundes setzen
        self.master.configure(bg = "#FFEC8B")

        # Erstelle ein Frame
        self.n = Frame(self.master, width = 500, height = 320)

        # ComboBox Feldnamen
        self.cb = Combobox(self.n, width = 25, values = [1, 2, 3])

        # Positioniere den Frame
        self.n.pack(side = TOP, anchor = NE, padx = 10, pady = 20)

        # Positionieren der ComboBox
        self.cb.place(x = 20, y = 20)

        # Button: Open
        self.b16 = Button(self.master, text = "Open", width = 10, command = self.openfile)
        self.b16.place(x = 15, y = 360)

    def openfile(self):
        ftype = [("vcd file", ".vcd")]
        title = "Open Filename"
        initial = "c:\\users\\ich\\pycharmprojects\\penval\\valdata\\"
        self.fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ftype, title = title, initialdir = initial)

    def symbol(self, z, a):
        return
```

Comment: how are you declaring the instance of this class to launch the app ?

Comment: its is done outside the class: just a call of the class

Comment: it is called from another module that declares a window

Comment: def gotoDE(self):
        root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
        myGui = example.Editor(root2)
this is the call to start the class

Comment: i will post it again, this time complete. sorry im a a beginner.

Comment: give me your mail adress and i will send you the complete code: mine is freund-th@t-online.de

Comment: it's better if you could post the code here, only the part of this base class that seems to hold the launching process, maybe you don't need the `Toplevel`

Comment: def gotoDE():
    root2 = Toplevel()
    myGui = Editor(root2)
    
root = Tk()
gotoDE()
root.mainloop()

Comment: why are you using a TopLevel widget here, something else is already plugged to `root` ? it may be easier to pass  `root` as master of `Editor`

Comment: it is still closing the frame n in the class Editor

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The main window still exists after the dialog goes away.

Comment: the main window stays but the frame n should in my program also stay open

Comment: This is a cut and paste duplicate of [Python tkinter filedialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984026/python-tkinter-filedialog) which is **strictly forbidden**.